# Reactive Banana 1.0.0 - Why is this old code breaking?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

Here's code that used to work (truncated appropriately I hope)

```
makeNetworkDescription :: forall t . Frameworks t => Parameters -> Moment t ()
makeNetworkDescription params = do
  eInput <- fromAddHandler (input params)
  eTick <- fromAddHandler (tick params)
  ..
let
    bResourceMap :: Behavior t ResourceMap
    bResourceMap = accumB initRmap $
      adjustMarket <$>
      bMarketRolls <@
      eTick
```

But now the types have changed.
we have:
    `makeNetworkDescription :: Parameters -> MomentIO ()`
and
    `accumB :: MonadMoment m => a -> Event (a -> a) -> m (Behavior a)`

say I change the definition of `bResourceMap` to

```
bResourceMap :: Behavior ResourceMap
bResourceMap = accumB initRmap $
               adjustMarket   <$>
               bMarketRolls   <@
               eTick
```

slightly off from the `accumB` definition, but let's see what happens.

`ghc` gives an error

```
Couldn't match type ‘Behavior ResourceMap’ with ‘ResourceMap’
Expected type: Behavior ResourceMap
  Actual type: Behavior (Behavior ResourceMap)
```

Right, because of the type of `accumB` the behavior needs to be within the context of a `MonadMoment`. Having a look at `MonadMoment` I find two instances

```
instance MonadMoment Moment where liftMoment = id
instance MonadMoment MomentIO where liftMoment = MIO . unM
```

So why did the actual type resolve to `Behavior (Behavior ResourceMap)`, the outer type has to be a `MonadMoment`, which doesn't match.

I'd like advice on how to resolve this type of problem, it happens with all my `Behavior` definitions.

Comment: just curious: is this a real or hobby project?

Comment: It's real, but not a game qua game. It's a game serving a purpose other than being just a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting your code to fit the new type of `accumB` should only take using a monadic bind rather than a `let` expression to define `bResourceMap`:

```
bResourceMap <- accumB initRmap (adjustMarket <$> bMarketRolls <@ eTick)
```

The type error you quote seems unrelated. My guess would be that `initRmap` was accidentally changed from being a `ResourceMap` to a `Behavior ResourceMap`, leading to the the type mismatch.

Comment: I've tried that but then other bindings fall out of scope. I'm thinking I need to add RecursiveDo to prevent that.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Indeed -- the changes mean you will need `MonadFix`/`RecursiveDo` in some form for mutually recursive definitions involving behaviours defined with `acummB`/`stepper`.

Comment: For future haskellers - the key is to use mdo instead of do. Syntactic sugar for rec and fix.